# Have a requirement to count number of paths and status of path in linux server

Tags: python, linux

```
mpatha (360014053bd9ea2a35914e39a556051cf) dm-0 LIO-ORG ,clusterstor 
size=4.0G features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw 
`- + - policy='service-time 0' prio=1 status=active 
   | - 2:0:0:0 sda 8:0 active ready running                      
   ` - 3:0:0:e sdb 8:10 active ready running
mpathb (360014053bd9ea2a35914e39a556051cf) dm-0 LIO-ORG ,clusterstor 
size=4.0G features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw 
`- + - policy='service-time 0' prio=1 status=active 
   | - 2:0:0:0 sda 8:01 active ready running
   ` - 3:0:0:e sdb 8:16 active ready running
     - 5:0:0:e sdc 8:18 active ready running
     - 6:0:0:e sdd 8:19 active ready running
ASM21 (360014053bd9ea2a35914e39a556051cf) dm-0 LIO-ORG ,clusterstor 
size=4.0G features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw 
`- + - policy='service-time 0' prio=1 status=active 
   | - 2:0:0:0 sdf 8:02 active ready running
   ` - 3:0:0:e sdg 8:11 active ready running
```

Above output is from an Linux server and requirement is to find number of paths for a disk

```
Expected output:

Disk: mpatha
Number of paths: 2
Disk: mpathb
Number of paths: 4
Disk: ASM21
Number of paths: 2
```

To make you understand what path is, for disk mpatha paths are as below and Number of paths should return 2

```
2:0:0:0 sda 8:0 active ready running
3:0:0:e sdb 8:10 active ready running
```

I tried my best to get a script working but it isn't working. Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expression to detect disks and paths

**Code**

```
import re

def report_path_stats(text):
    '''
        Uses regular expresssion to count disk paths
    '''
    node = re.compile(r'(\w+)\s\(')                                      # detects disk node
    path = re.compile(r'.*?\s([a-z]{3})\s[\d:]+\sactive ready running')  # detects subnodes or paths for node

    results = {}
    for line in text.split('\n'):
        node_ = node.search(line)

        if node_:
            disk = node_.group(1)
            results[disk] = []
        else:
            path_ = path.search(line)
            if path_:
                results[disk].append(path_.group(1))

    for k, v in results.items():
        print(f'Disk: {k}')
        print(f'Number of paths: {len(v)}')
```

**Test**

```
s = '''mpatha (360014053bd9ea2a35914e39a556051cf) dm-0 LIO-ORG ,clusterstor 
size=4.0G features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw 
`- + - policy='service-time 0' prio=1 status=active 
   | - 2:0:0:0 sda 8:0 active ready running                      
   ` - 3:0:0:e sdb 8:10 active ready running
mpathb (360014053bd9ea2a35914e39a556051cf) dm-0 LIO-ORG ,clusterstor 
size=4.0G features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw 
`- + - policy='service-time 0' prio=1 status=active 
   | - 2:0:0:0 sda 8:01 active ready running
   ` - 3:0:0:e sdb 8:16 active ready running
     - 5:0:0:e sdc 8:18 active ready running
     - 6:0:0:e sdd 8:19 active ready running
ASM21 (360014053bd9ea2a35914e39a556051cf) dm-0 LIO-ORG ,clusterstor 
size=4.0G features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw 
`- + - policy='service-time 0' prio=1 status=active 
   | - 2:0:0:0 sdf 8:02 active ready running
   ` - 3:0:0:e sdg 8:11 active ready running'''

report_path_stats(s)
```

**Output**

```
Disk: mpatha
Number of paths: 2
Disk: mpathb
Number of paths: 4
Disk: ASM21
Number of paths: 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works as expected. I need to learn more about regex

Comment: @sharath--glad to help.  Let me know if the regex expressions are not clear.  A good place to experiment and get an explanation of expressions is regex101.com (try them in Python mode).

Comment: Would definitely checkout regex101.com.